# Как добавить элемент не из Layout ListView в нужную позицию ListView?

Tags: android

Есть ListVIew из TextView, мне нужно в 10 позиции listView между 10 и 11 элементом добавить Switch.

Есть такой вариант создать layout с TextView и Switcch, Switch изначально сделать INVISIBLE а после 10 сделать VISIBLE. Но такой вариант вроде на происзодительность влиять будет, так как по сути я ради 1 элемента создаю аж N - количество...

Есть ли более оптимальный вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создать `Switch` в коде, при помощи `Java`:

   ```
   Switch switch = new Switch(context);
   layout.addView(switch);
   ```
2. Создать отдельный `Layout` в `XML` со `Switch` на случай, когда он нужен, и делать так:

   ```
   if(needSwitch) {
       convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.with_switch, null);
   } else {
       convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.without_switch, null);
   }
   ```

   Естественно, надо придумать, как быть с `ViewHolder`'ом
3. Сделать так, как вы придумали - показывать свич только тогда, когда он нужен.

Comment: А почему Layout? может ListView.addView?

Comment: @xTIGRx, а вам он нужен как отдельный элемент списка, или как часть элемента списка?

Comment: Ну получается что как элемент  списка ListView. просто везде TextView  а в 10 позиции должно быть помимо TextVIew еще и Switch

Comment: @xTIGRx,  `Switch` рядом с  `TextVIew` в одном элементе списка? Или один элемент - `TextVIew`, и еще один элемент `Switch`?   Если `Switch` последний вообще должен быть, то для этого можно использовать footer

Comment: TextView и Switch как один элемент

Comment: @xTIGRx, значит, надо положить `TextView` в какой-нибудь `Layout`, и при надобности в него добавлять `Switch`. Это если делать по первому варианту.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в адаптере переопределить getItemViewType и в getView возвращать нужную вьюху в зависимости от типа. Ниже пример, накидал вслепую.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (needSwitch) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        ViewWithoutSwitch view;
        if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof ViewWithoutSwitch) {
            view = (ViewWithoutSwitch) convertView;
        } else {
            view = new ViewWithoutSwitch(parent.getContext());
        }
        view.bind(getItem(position));
        return view;
    } else {
        ViewWithSwitch view;
        if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof ViewWithSwitch) {
            view = (ViewWithSwitch) convertView;
        } else {
            view = new ViewWithSwitch(parent.getContext());
        }
        view.bind(getItem(position));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Можно сделать по другому. Сделать одну вьюху и добавить туда Switch, а через bind выставлять нужный visibility. Обязательно реюзайте convertView.